# How to log django performance statistics on production server?

Tags: python, django, performance, logging, database-performance

I'm looking for something that will get me the same info as I got via [Django debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar), but in form of log file rather than template overlay. It must be is safe to run  in production environment. I'm most concerned about cpu time and number/time of database query's.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

If your focus is indeed lower down on the stack (e.g. queries, CPU load, memory) and you don't Django specific stats, then [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) is a good candidate.